# How to construct a nontrigonal curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

$C$ is a smooth projective curve over an algebraically  closed field, we say $C$ is trigonal if $C$ admits a degree 3 cover of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. I could give example which is trigonal. Now I want to construct a curve which is not trigonal. My idea is following:

If $C$ is trigonal, then there will be a linear system $|D|$ in $C$ such that $\mathrm{deg} D=3$ and $\mathrm{dim}|D|=1$. So my ideal is to construct a curve such that for all effective divsor of degree 3 in $C$, $\mathrm{dim} |D|=0$. However it seems not so easy to get such a curve.

Could you give an example?

Comment: I vaguely remember that for high-enough genus (at least 3?), a curve cannot be both hyperelliptic and trigonal, so just pick a hyperelliptic curve of high enough degree. Sorry that I can't remember the full details at the moment.

Comment: To be clear, by not trigonal do you literally mean that, or do you mean "admits no map to $\mathbb P^1$ of degree less than $4$?" A curve which is both hyperelliptic and trigonal is, by virtue of those maps, a curve of type $(2,3)$ on $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ which makes its genus $(3-1)(2-1)=2$, so a hyperelliptic curve of genus $\ge 3$ does the job in the former case. If you actually want something with a minimal pencil of degree $4$, that's a little trickier. I think you can take a "suitably general" double cover of an elliptic or hyperelliptic curve, but there may be simpler ways.

Comment: @KReiser I think you are right. I can prove that a curve of genus at least three can not be both hyperelliptic and trigonal. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @TabesBridges For not trigonal I just mean admits no map to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ of degree is exactly 3. I have found such an example.

Comment: @Mike glad to help! Might I suggest writing up what you found as an answer to your own question so others may learn from it in the future?

Answer (score 3):

If the canonical curve is an intersection of quadrics, it is not trigonal. So, the simplest example of a non-trigonal (and not hyperelliptic) curve is a complete intersection of three quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$.